# Android JSON data in to a listview not working

Tags: java, android, json, listview

I 'm retrieving mysql data from mysql database using json. It is working correctly. But Now I'm doing is put that data into android listview. I have collect one type of data(item_name) and put it into a arraylist. then I have add it to a listview. When I run the program it was crashed. here is my code

---

public class FirstActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

```
private TextView view;
private String startPosition = "0";
private String endPosition = "5";
private List<ProductData> productList = new ArrayList<ProductData>();;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_first);

    this.data(view);
    productListView();

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }
}

private void productListView() {
    ArrayAdapter<ProductData> adapter = new MyListAdapter();
    ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.productList);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
}

private class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ProductData> {
    public MyListAdapter() {
        super(FirstActivity.this, R.layout.item_layout, productList);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View itemView = convertView;
        if(itemView == null) {
            itemView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item_layout, parent, false);
        }

        ProductData currentProduct = productList.get(position);

        TextView itemName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.item_name);
        itemName.setText(currentProduct.getProductName());

        return itemView;
    }

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.first, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first,
                container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
}

public void data(View view) {

    Log.d("inside onPreExe", "on click");
    Async(view);

}

private class ProcessProduct extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();

        Log.d("startPosition", startPosition);
        Log.d("endPosition", endPosition);

        Log.d("inside onPreExe", "inside onPreExe");

    }

    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ProductData productdata = new ProductData();
        JSONObject json = productdata.productDetails(startPosition,
                endPosition);
        Log.d("inside", "doInBack");

        // for next 5 items
        int startpostion = Integer.parseInt(startPosition) + 5;
        startPosition = Integer.toString(startpostion);

        return json;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(json);




        Log.d("inside onPreExe", "inside onPostExe");

        try {

            JSONArray products = json.getJSONArray("product");
            for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject product = products.getJSONObject(i);

                String item_name = product.getString("item_name");

                productList.get(i).setProductName(item_name);

                Log.d("item name", item_name);



            }

        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}

public void Async(View view) {
    Log.d("inside onPreExe", "inside Async");
    new ProcessProduct().execute();
}
```

}

---

here is the logcat

```
05-03 12:34:32.400: D/inside onPreExe(1793): inside onPreExe
05-03 12:34:32.420: D/AndroidRuntime(1793): Shutting down VM
05-03 12:34:32.420: W/dalvikvm(1793): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb1aa7ba8)
05-03 12:34:32.520: D/dalvikvm(1793): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 274K, 9% free 3493K/3836K, paused 44ms, total 53ms
05-03 12:34:32.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1793): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-03 12:34:32.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1793): Process: com.shopsystem.anything, PID: 1793
05-03 12:34:32.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1793): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.shopsystem.anything/com.shopsystem.anything.FirstActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-03 12:34:32.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1793):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
05-03 12:34:32.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1793):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
05-03 12:34:32.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1793):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
05-03 12:34:32.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1793):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
05-03 12:34:32.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1793):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
05-03 12:34:32.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1793):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
05-03 12:34:32.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1793):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
05-03 12:34:32.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1793):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-03 12:34:32.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1793):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-03 12:34:32.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1793):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
05-03 12:34:32.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1793):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
05-03 12:34:32.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1793):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-03 12:34:32.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1793): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-03 12:34:32.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1793):     at com.shopsystem.anything.FirstActivity.productListView(FirstActivity.java:50)
05-03 12:34:32.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1793):     at com.shopsystem.anything.FirstActivity.onCreate(FirstActivity.java:39)
05-03 12:34:32.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1793):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
05-03 12:34:32.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1793):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
05-03 12:34:32.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1793):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this operation inside DoInBackground() method and not in postExecute() It is used to display only UI.

```
     try {

        JSONArray products = json.getJSONArray("product");
        for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject product = products.getJSONObject(i);

            String item_name = product.getString("item_name");

            productList.get(i).setProductName(item_name);

            Log.d("item name", item_name);



        }

    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: no friend. there are no issue. it works fine when I remove listview thing. problem is in listview function.

Comment: ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.productList);
    list.setAdapter(adapter); use this in postExecute()

Comment: See this..Displaying All Products in ListView  in this link.. http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/

Comment: I post it above. check it friend.

Comment: see the logic..initially you are calling this method.    productListView(); so it directly goes to the method and displaying null exception. remove that method and display the listview and adapter in postExecute

Comment: moreover what is this? public void Async(View view) {
    Log.d("inside onPreExe", "inside Async");
    new ProcessProduct().execute();
} you are using any button click to call the method? if not means, you can call this ProcessProduct method in OnCreate() itself. see the android hive link steps how it follows.

Comment: no. I want to load only 5 items in oncreate after that if user click more button then next 5 items will load. that is why I have done there.